# Mobilefirst fails trying to logout in an adapter base authentication

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, hybrid-mobile-app, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

im working with mobilefirst 7.1 in an hybrid app currentrly running in a production server, the problem is that now the WL.Client.logout stops working and always returns in de logcat:

```
[https://mydomain/MyContext/authorization/v1/authorization] failure. state: 500, response: The server was unable to process the request from the application. Please try again later.
```

But all the application runs well login / adapters calls...

Here is my code were i run my logout, that always goes trought the failure callback:

```
  Login.logout=function(){
        Utils.mostrarBusyIndicator("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        WL.Client.logout("AuthRealm", {
            onSuccess : Login.logoutSuccess,
            onFailure : Login.logoutFailure
        });
    }
```

this is the log in the messages.log:

```
[2/24/16 9:54:24:788 ART] 00000311 org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor             E An unhandled exception occurred which will be propagated to the container.
[2/24/16 9:54:24:789 ART] 00000311 com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.util.ApplicationErrorUtils           E SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class 'com.ibm.ws.jaxrs.JAXRSRuntimeDelegate.getInstanceForThreadPrivileged:189'
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.wink.common.internal.runtime.RuntimeDelegateImpl cannot be cast to javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs.JAXRSRuntimeDelegate.getInstanceForThreadPrivileged(JAXRSRuntimeDelegate.java:189)
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs.JAXRSRuntimeDelegate.access$000(JAXRSRuntimeDelegate.java:42)
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs.JAXRSRuntimeDelegate$1.run(JAXRSRuntimeDelegate.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs.JAXRSRuntimeDelegate$1.run(JAXRSRuntimeDelegate.java:113)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs.JAXRSRuntimeDelegate.getInstanceForThread(JAXRSRuntimeDelegate.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.jaxrs.JAXRSRuntimeDelegate.createResponseBuilder(JAXRSRuntimeDelegate.java:99)
    at javax.ws.rs.core.Response$ResponseBuilder.newInstance(Response.java:60)
    at javax.ws.rs.core.Response.status(Response.java:256)
    at javax.ws.rs.core.Response.ok(Response.java:215)
    at com.worklight.authorization.endpoint.authorization.AuthorizationEndpoint.handleLogout(AuthorizationEndpoint.java:138)
    at com.worklight.authorization.endpoint.authorization.AuthorizationEndpoint.authorizeClient(AuthorizationEndpoint.java:103)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.InvokeMethodHandler.handleRequest(InvokeMethodHandler.java:63)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:33)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.CreateInvocationParametersHandler.handleRequest(CreateInvocationParametersHandler.java:54)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandler.handleRequest(AbstractHandler.java:34)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleResourceMethod(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:151)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:65)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindRootResourceHandler.handleRequest(FindRootResourceHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.HeadMethodHandler.handleRequest(HeadMethodHandler.java:53)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.OptionsMethodHandler.handleRequest(OptionsMethodHandler.java:46)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.SearchResultHandler.handleRequest(SearchResultHandler.java:33)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.ResourceInvocation.handleRequest(ResourceInvocation.java:92)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Requests.handleRequest(Requests.java:76)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:67)
    at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:52)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:207)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:154)
    at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1285)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:776)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:473)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:135)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:89)
    at com.worklight.authorization.server.AuthorizationServerFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationServerFilter.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
    at com.worklight.analytics.AnalyticsFilter.doFilter(AnalyticsFilter.java:124)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:1017)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1139)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:81)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:927)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:955)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any help?

Comment: if you build your project older version CLI . this problem might be occur

Comment: ive build and deploy one time my project with cli, but later i did it with my eclipse / worklightconsole, The problem persist

Comment: may be also older your eclipse/worklightconsole is not  delete everything from server and restart ,redeploy war file ,application ,adapter .

Comment: also onSuccess of logout try to use WL.Client.reloadApp(); and before login check the relam is authenticated or not with WL.Client.isUserAuthenticated("AuthRealm")

Comment: ive just update my post with the messages.log error (logout works fine in my desktop browser environment)

Comment: Are you sure you  logged in to AuthRealm before calling the logout ?

Comment: @user2449016, any updates to this question?